# Diffrence between a dot and comma in cost value in php

Tags: php, currency

My client(from denmark) give the value to use in cost value in php.

He said " Use this , The Cost is 50.000 Dkr half product , 200.000 Dkr. for full product. "

i am confused in comma and dot ? what is correct value ? its 50.000 or 50,000.

Comment: It depends on where you live ;-). If you look at what the Dkr is worth, and take into account that its uncommon to have _three_ decimal zeroes in a price, I'd say in this case, the dot is __not__ a decimal comma.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php... [i18n/L10n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization)

Comment: Are you storing the value in the DB? Are you gonna make mathematical operations with it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system

Comment: Don't mix internal representation with display representation

Comment: @SyedArsalanHussainShah: Look at Zend_Locales, the code that deals with this has been written already - use it

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem actually PHP has native extensions for this with http://php.net/locale and http://php.net/intl so there is no need for a third party component like Zend_Locale

Comment: @Gordon: Right you are there, I should've suggested `Zend_Currency` coupled with any locale extension...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a coding question

Commas are used in the English convention to separate thousands (50,000 = fifty thousand. 50.000 = fifty point zero zero zero)

In Continental Europe commas are used as the decimal separator (50,5 = fifty and a half)

Please do a bit of research before your next question. This one is easily answered [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)